# Coordinating popups to add new object with VF page showing list of all objs for a given parent

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to create a custom "Create/View comment" Page where the user can create new comment as well as view all his previous comments.

Page 1:

```
 <apex:dataTable value="{!commentdata}" var="comments">      

          <apex:column headerValue="Title">
            <apex:inputText value="{!title}"/> 
          </apex:column>

          <apex:column headerValue="Comment Section">
          <apex:inputText value="{!Comment}"/>

          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="CreatedBy">
          <apex:inputText value="{!CreatedBy}"/>
          </apex:column>
          </apex:dataTable>

          <apex:column headerValue="Timestamp">
            <apex:inputText value="{!timestamp}"/>
          </apex:column>
      <apex:commandButton value="New comment" onclick="PopUp(); return false"/> //when the user clicks on this button it would open up a pop up where the user can enter the comment and click save
```

Page 2:

```
<apex:inputTextarea value="{!Comment}"/>
<apex:commandbutton value="Save" action="{!savecomment}"/>
```

When the user clicks on the save button it would close the current screen and update the view comment datatable and the new comment will always be on top.

Can someone please help me with the controller for the same? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to get back to the parent window; I usually create a page called "closePopup" that contains the following code:

```
<apex:page>
<script>
window.opener.location.refresh();
window.close();
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Your function savecomment() as listed on page 2 should return a pagereference to closepopup:

```
public pagereference savecomment() {
    // try to save, return null on error
    // okay, now we redirect:
    return page.closepopup;
}
```

---

Based on the comments, here is one sample communication scheme:

## Parent Page

```
<apex:page ...>
    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:actionFunction action="{!addcomment}" name="addComment" reRender="form">
            <apex:param name="comment" value=""/>
            <apex:param name="createdby" value=""/>
        </apex:actionFunction>
        <!-- rest of your code here -->
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

## Popup Page

```
<apex:page ...>
    <apex:form id="form">
        <script>
            function onComplete() {
                if({!completed}) {
                    window.opener.addComment("{!JSENCODE(comment)}", "{!JSENCODE(createdby)}");
                   window.close();
                }
            }
        </script>
        <!-- your code here -->
        <apex:commandButton action="{!savecomment}" reRender="form" oncomplete="onComplete()" />
    </apex:form>
```

### How This Works

On the first page, we define an actionFunction; this will be called by the second page in order to save the data back into the view state.

On the second page, we add a JavaScript function that will be dynamically reRendered and executed when a successful save occurs. `Completed` should be a boolean that is defaulted to false, and set to true in `savecomment` when the save occurred successfully.

Comment: Thank you sfdcfox. Will try that. Also, how do I save value from one page to another? Here the comments are not getting stored on any salesforce custom/standard objects. It is temporarily saved on the view state. I want to save it in such a way that the recent comment should be at the top.

Comment: If that's the case, you'll need to call a function on the parent page. This drastically changes the solution to your problem. I'll draft up some code for you tonight.

Comment: It would be a great help if you could do that. Thank you so much. If it is not too much trouble I would also like to add one more thing. When I save the comment it should autopopulate Created By and Timestamp. The title is currently defaulted to Comment so I don't have to worry about it.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to use this? I think it might be better to use a lightbox and save yourself the hassle of passing between windows (unless you've got a great reason). Popup windows to edit records are very last decade-ish.

Comment: The comment information will saved on a third party app through a service and that is why we are not storing it on salesforce at the moment. For the moment what needs to happen is pass the comment information from one page to another along with the created by and time stamp  when I click save.

Comment: @user2603196 I expect you will need some tweaks, but I hope this framework gets you started. Good luck; cross-window communication is still spotty unless you're committed to only HTML5 (and thus, ignoring IE9 and below), in which case you can use postMessage, which is a Godsend.